# Getting the returned value from async function in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, async-await, javascript-objects

```
async function someFunction() {
    try {
      var key =  await dec.awsDecrypt('dev-frontend')
      return key;
    } catch(err) {
    }
}

//calling the function 
const result = someFunction()
```

Above I have an asynchronous that returns the value `key`. I'm trying to retrieve that value by assigning the function to a variable `result`, but when trying I get `Promise { <pending> }` as a response. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to `await someFunction()` or otherwise handle it as a promise.

Comment: ^ Which would be `someFunction().then(result => { /* do stuff with result ... */ })`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `someFunction` will return a promise because you put the async keyword before it.

You are going to need to await it as well.

```
const result = someFunction().then(console.log)
```

or

```
const result = someFunction().then((result)=>console.log(result))
```

or you can run the whole program inside what is called an immediately invoked function. That way you can make your `immediately invoked function` async as well and use await in there.